# Why is slideDown Expanding an Image From the Top Left Hand Corner Instead of the Entire Width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a series of pictures that I would like to `slideDown()` from left to right (creating a waterfall effect).  I create the waterfall effect using `setInterval()`:

```
var i = 1;
var numberCount = 5;
var counter = window.setInterval(function(){
            $("#instagram-pictures .instagram-picture:nth-child(" + i + ")").slideDown(1200);
            if(i === numberCount){
                window.clearInterval(counter);
            }
            else{
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }, 400);
```

This works without a hitch except the `slideDown` part.  For some reason, my pictures are not sliding down from the width of the entire top line, rather they are "expanding out" from the top left hand corner.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jydB3/2/)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.slideDown()` animates the `height` of an element, not it's position. You're allowing the `width` of each picture to be automatically determined based on the `height`. So as the height changes, it's determining new widths as well, and animating a diagonal stretch.

If you give the images a fixed width you'll get the downward animation you're after.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Answer (score 1):

Try ths:

Give each image a fixed `width`

```
.instagram-picture{
    display: none;
    width:100px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

The `width` is determined based on the `height` and since the `height` is changing when the image slides down, the `width` changes with it. Therefore, setting a fixed `width` will fix your problem!

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jydB3/3/)**